# Combine queries and order results by score

Tags: elasticsearch

I want Elastic to execute multiple (multi-match) queries and sort them by score. The score of each query should be calculated indepentent of the other queries (which is different from what I have googled so far with the bool/should clause I think).

Example:

Query 1:

```
"multi_match" : {
                  "query":      "test",
                  "fields":     ["a", "b", "c"],
                  "tie_breaker": 0.2,
                  "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                }
```

Query 2:

```
"multi_match" : {
                  "query":      "test2",
                  "fields":     ["a", "b", "c"],
                  "tie_breaker": 0.2,
                  "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                }
```

Combine both results and order by score. How can I do that with Elastic?

Comment: if it is in different query, you can sort it in post processing ie use `sort()` function in javascript.

Comment: I'd like to merge these queries in Elastic and let Elastic sort the results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Dis Max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) query is what you are looking for:

> A query that generates the union of documents produced by its
>   subqueries, and that scores each document with the maximum score for
>   that document as produced by any subquery, plus a tie breaking
>   increment for any additional matching subqueries.